# invalidation or spinner issue?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have been searching through here for quite some time now, but was unable to find my current issue (although a lot of other ones).

I have made a spinner with a listener, and inside that listener I am trying to invoke an invalidation of a ListView that is presented at onCreate.
Now, the spinner contains languages, and depending on the language, different stuff shall be presented in the ListView. The issue is that when I select an item in the spinner, nothing happens at all.

My main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
private ListView termsListView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String selectedLanguage = "";
    createListView(selectedLanguage);
}

public void createListView(String selectedLanguage)
{
    termsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.termsListView);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Language", 0);
    String language = sharedPref.toString();


 // Initialize the terms array
    Term [] items = {
            new Term(1, "Acceptance", "The process of assessing whether a system satisfies all its requirements", false, "Acceptans", "", language),
            new Term(2, "Acceptance test", "A test that assesses whether a system satisfies all its requirements", false, "Acceptans test", "", language),
            new Term(3, "Activity diagram", "A diagram type in UML which models the flow of actions in a system or in a component including data flows and areas of responsibility where necessary", false, "Aktivitets diagram", "", language),
            new Term(4, "Actor", "1. Generally in RE: A person, a system or a technical device in the context of a system that interacts with the system.2. Especially in goal-oriented RE: a person, a system or a technical device that may act and process information in order to achieve some goals", false, "Aktör", "", language),
    };
    ArrayAdapter<Term> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Term>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    termsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    termsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DisplayDescription.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, item);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    createSpinner();

}
public void createSpinner(){
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.languageSpinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.languages_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public void addListenertoSpinner(){
    final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.languageSpinner);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String spinnerValue = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Language", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editedPrefs = sharedPref.edit();
            editedPrefs.putString("Language", spinnerValue);
            editedPrefs.commit();
            termsListView.invalidate();

            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


//@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

And my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollMainActivityLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityMainLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/selectLanguageTitle" />
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/languageSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/languages_prompt"/>
  <Button 
        android:id="@+id/languageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/languageSpinner"
        android:text="@string/languageButtonTitle"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/glossaryTitle" />
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/termsListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Term.java

```
package se.inceptive.irebglossary;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
//import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Term extends MainActivity{
private int termId;
private String termNameEnglish;
private String termDescriptionEnglish;
private boolean termJA;
private String termNameSwedish;
private String termDescriptionSwedish;
private static ArrayList<Term> terms;
//  private String selectedLanguage;
private Context context;
private String termSetLanguage;


 public Term(){
        super();
 }

 public Term(int collectId, String collectEnglish, String collectDescriptionEnglish, boolean collectJA, String collectSwedish, String collectDescriptionSwedish, String collectLanguage) {
        super();
        this.termId = collectId;
        this.termNameEnglish = collectEnglish;
        this.termDescriptionEnglish = collectDescriptionEnglish;
        this.termJA = collectJA;
        this.termNameSwedish = collectSwedish;
        this.termDescriptionSwedish = collectDescriptionSwedish;
        this.termSetLanguage = collectLanguage;

        if(terms == null)
            terms = new ArrayList<Term>();

        terms.add(this);
 }

 public static String getDescriptionFromName(String name)
 {
     for(Term term : terms)
     {
         if(name.equals(term.termNameEnglish))
             return term.termDescriptionEnglish;
         if(name.equals(term.termNameSwedish))
             return term.termDescriptionSwedish;
     }
     return null;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     //String selectedLanguage = Context.getPreferences().toString();
     //String selectedLanguage = this.context.getResources().getString(R.string.selectedLanguage);

     if(termSetLanguage.equals("English"))
     {
         return this.termNameEnglish;
     }
     if(termSetLanguage.equals("Svenska"))
     {
         return this.termNameSwedish;
     }
     else
     {
         return this.termNameEnglish;
     }
 }
```

}

Also, I do not get any logCat errors.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you called `addListenertoSpinner();` ? Call it after  declaring your Spinner

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String languages={"English","Spanish","french"};

    termsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.termsListView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listdata(0));
    termsListView.setAdapter(adapter);


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.languageSpinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listdata(pos));
            termsListView.setAdapter(adapter);// here we will update the listview data according to selected language



            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });





}



public String[] listdata(int language)

{
    if(language==0)
    {
        String languagearray[]={"English-One","English-Two"};
        return languagearray;
    }

    else if(language==1)
    {
        String languagearray[]={"Spanish-One","Spanish-Two"};
        return languagearray;
    }
    else
    {
        String languagearray[]={"French-One","French-Two"};
        return languagearray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Placed it at the bottom of createSpinner(), but nothing still happens when selecting another value in the spinner.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like invalidate(); does not work... If I change the values of the spinner, then the value inside the spinner changes, but not the ListView. But if I change the value inside the spinner, and then click on an item in the ListView, and then go back again, then the items inside the ListView has changed to the spinners value. Strange...

Comment: you need to set the adapter for listview again, if you want to invalidate your listview.

Comment: What values you want to be updated on listview, when spinner changes?

Comment: Only the name of the item, which is the 5th column of the array.

Comment: Name of what item? selected spinner item?

Comment: Let's see, the items in the ListView are supposed to change when I change the value on the spinner. The items in the ListView are an edited array that are edited in the class Term.java (posted in the question). The array that comes out from Term.java is the array that populates the ListView.
So the spinner is supposed to tell Term.java to use the Swedish name instead of the English name in the array.

Comment: Tried your edited answer, but it didn't seem to work. What happens now is that it is hard to click on anything in the ListView and the spinner. And the ListView does not change, it seems to be trapped in a never-ending loop.

Comment: See my answer now. It will give you an idea about updating listview according to spinner change